# scollector installation from source issue

Tags: linux, go, amazon-ec2, scollector

I've been following this [link](http://bosun.org/scollector/) to install scollector on an AWS ec2 instance running HBase. The link asks to run this command:
`go get bosun.org/cmd/scollector` to install from source. When I run it, I get the following output: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. This obviously is very unhelpful, how do I set this right?

There's a linux binary in the above link that I probably could use to install scollector but I don't know how to install a linux binary(assuming I manage to upload the file to ec2). Can anyone help on that(if the first problem is not clear enough)?

Answer (score 2):

In order to install scollector from source you need Go version >1.6 to build bosun.

Alternatively you can download binary file and place it somewhere, like /home/user/go/bin/ and don't forget to change permissions

```
chmod +x scollector-linux-amd64
```

check it

```
./scollector-linux-amd64 -version
```

you'll have version 0.6.0 if you compiled it from source